# Hide Window Load Overlay in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a loading window preventing users from accessing the site contents until the page finishing loading. I have different code for IE (I'm using IE 11 w/Windows 7):

```
    <body>

.........

    <div id="loading"> <img id="loading-image" src="images/trs_loading.gif" width="500" height"226" alt="Loading..." />
        <p class="loading_text">Rich content loading in progress . . . it's definitely worth the wait! &#9835;</p>

    <br />

        <p class="loading_text">In the meantime, like our official <a href="https://www.facebook.com/TheRhythmShop?fref=ts" class="loading_link" target="_blank">Facebook page.</p></a>

    </div>
    <script>
        <? if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') === false): ?>
        $(window).load(function() {
         $('#loading').hide();
        });
        <? else: ?>
        window.onload = function() {
            $('#loading').hide();
        };
        <? endif; ?>
    </script>
    </body>
```

The problem is even after the overlay disappears from IE it eventually crashes from the harddrive light that keeps staying lit continuously. The page does not respond to mouse events.

The address is http://www.therhythmshop.com

Comment: Works for me, which IE-version do you use?

Comment: You don't need an if statement, your two handlers as written are one and the same. However, the first one allows you to add multiple handlers to the same event, so I would suggest using that one.

Comment: Also, your page in IE is throwing an error, you should debug it with IE's developer tools: `'encodeURIComponent' is undefined`